# How to listen connection to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm writing a *SQL Server* listen connection application;

If a connection is not available (connection cable is disconnected / damaged) at any time during startup or processing, my APP will sleep until the connection is available. When the connection is restored, the app will wake up and start executing SQL commands.

Please could you advise on a method needed to listen for SQL Connections.

Note: I think I need to understand a listen mechanism that similar to mechanism of the `MessageQueue.Receive()` method.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Typically you only open a connection when executing a transaction or a batch of transactions to talk to the SQL Server dB and close the connection afterwards. So if `Connection.Open()` causes an exception you could go to sleep and keep pinging the connection periodically until it doesn't raise an exception. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson: you have already said: "So if Connection.Open() causes an exception you could go to sleep and keep pinging the connection periodically until it doesn't raise an exception", but my demand is my app will sleep (not consume CPU resource) and wait until connection is available (network cable is plug or another reason), it will wake up and do work.

Comment: -a reply 5 months on is pretty meh.. don't really have an answer for you, unless you watch a SQL service start (via event log) you won't be notified, AFAIK there is not a way unless you keep pinging/polling. It would be good if there was like a 'FolderWatcher' library for db connection availability. Sorry I do not know of one.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I've already learnt about this problem for a very long time, but still have no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its a complex thing to write whole implementation i can give you pointers
You need a timer to monitor whether the internet connection is available or not. I have written partial logic complete according to your need. You may need to monitor your connection link connect/reconnect by keeping a private variable.

```
public class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// External method for checking internet access:
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

    /// <summary>
    /// C# callable method to check internet access
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
    {
        int Description;
        return InternetGetConnectedState(out Description, 0);
    }

    private static Timer aTimer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Fired when a connection is made to the server
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler ConnectedToNetwork;

    public void OnConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            if (null != ConnectedToNetwork)
            {
                ConnectedToNetwork(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fired when loses its connection to the server
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler DisconnectedFromNetwork;


    /// <summary>
    /// Clears server notifications
    /// </summary>
    public void OnDisconnected()
    {
        try
        {

            if (null != DisconnectedFromNetwork)
            {
                DisconnectedFromNetwork(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }


    public void Intialize()
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000); //Timer will start when your application is started
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program... ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsConnectedToInternet())
        {
            OnConnected();
            //Code to APP will wake up and execute SQL commands.
        }
        else
        {
            OnDisconnected();
        }
    }
}

// DBClass 'ClientCodeSubscription' should verify whetehr the DB is up and running. 
class DBClass
{
    public bool DBServerIsRunning { get; set; }
    //In DB area
    private void ClientCodeSubscription()
    {
        if (DBServerIsRunning) //Check to see if DB service is running.
        {
            Example ex = new Example();
            ex.ConnectedToNetwork += Example_ConnectedToNetwork; //this is your client code probably in                this case the DB
        }

    }

    static void Example_ConnectedToNetwork(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but I had assumption from the question that the Database  Watcher wasn't in the same box as the DB.
So Modem/LAN active signal isn't same as SQL Server uptime. 

@Alex, Jeremy Thompson And Srikanth suggestions will work, but it depends on your usecase. Is this APP a Monitoring Tool (After Alerting going to sleep till it's up again) ? or is it just a writer to DB.  I personally lean towards Jeremy's Suggestion if its a simple writer to DB.

Comment: Updated answer with the publisher/subscriber mechanism. Once the Connection available all the clients(Here DB) who are subscribed will be notified.

Comment: thanks for your answer! but I want my APP don't have to use timer or while loop, because they are not good. I guess I should use Monitor mechanism, but i think it's very difficult. if you have any ideas, please talk to me. thanks in advance!

Comment: Srikanth, your app have used a Timer that mean in each every two seconds your app will check connection one time. I want my app won't use Timer or while loop that mean if connection is available(connected), it will generate a ConnectedToNetwork event automatically, if connection is disconnected, it will generate a DisconnectedFromNetwork event automatically.

Comment: @GIANGPZO interesting could you post your answer once your objective completed.